# Java downcasting with reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflection, java-6, downcast

I hava a model in Java 1.6 similar to this example:

```
public class Animal {
  public String color;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Float height;
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
  public Integer wings;
}
```

Now I want cast from Animal to anyone child. I know that It's throw a runtime exception for forbidden cast. So I think that it's possible have a children only with the parent fields with the help of a constructor and java reflection. Example:

```
public class Animal {
  public String color;

  public Animal(Animal old){
    //Set all fields by reflection. but how!
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Float height;

  public Dog (Animal old){
     super(old);
  }
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
  public Integer wings;
  public Bird (Animal old){
     super(old);
  }
}
```

**But how set all de parent fields with reflection?**

**SOLUTION BY Thinaesh** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697270/1474638) Thanks!.
I'm using Spring so only I need to do in the parent constructor the next:

```
public Animal(Animal old){
  super();
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(old, this);
}

  public Dog(Animal old){
  super(old);
}

public Bird(Animal old){
  super(old);
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you don't need them, use primitives instead of primitive wrapper objects

Comment: How is that supposed to work? You cannot set a ``height`` (a field from class Dog) to Animal, as there is no such field.

Comment: @f1sh I don't want set children field's. I want a children object with the parent fields setted. Obviously that the children fields must have null values because in parent I don't have this fields.

Comment: So you want to cast a Bird to a Dog?  If you don't care about the class hierarchy you have, you can just have all Animals.  BTW Don't use wrappers or float unless you have to. Use primitives and double instead.

Comment: @earnaz what does that have to do with reflection? In the constructor ``Animal(Animal old)`` you simply state ``this.color = old.color;``

Comment: @PeterLawrey No! I wont a Dog or a Bird from an Animal. For example I have an Animal with black color, and I wan't to have a Dog with black color and Bird with black color from Animal class.

Comment: @f1sh Yes I can do it, but the class Animal could change and I do not want to forget a field in the allocation.

Comment: @earnaz all the fields of Animal are copied in the constructor of Animal, so if you change that class, you just change the constructor.

Comment: @f1sh In my real class I have 15 constructor and 26 fields. If I change the class I do not want to be worried that someone forget a field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try BeanUtils.copyProperties from Apache commons library.(Same thing available in Spring's BeanUtils class.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some clarification through the comments to your question:

All you are doing here is copying values in a class's constructor. There is no need for reflection. Reflection should be avoided unless there is no other way.

Comment: Yes, Reflection should be avoided but my ask is how copy fields with reflection.